# MX priority records to balance requests

Tags: dns, mx-record

I have the MX records of one domain pointing to a server handling the email through a PHP script. That server is just ONE of the multiple instances I have in a pool.

The problem is that I think I'm going to saturate this server soon.

I guess if I can use the MX records to balance requests and "send emails" to different servers...

a) Do I have to put different MX records with same priority to balance them ?

```
 MX  10  ip1
 MX  10  ip2
 MX  10  ip3
```

b) or with different priority ?

```
 MX  10  ip1
 MX  20  ip2
 MX  30  ip3
```

c) any other idea ?

Thank you !

Answer (score 0):

For different levels of priority, the lowest-numbered records are the most preferred. This phrasing can be confusing, and so the preference number is sometimes referred to as the distance: smaller distances are more preferable.

When two MX records have the same priority the sender SMTP server selects a random MX record of the two.

So for equal balancing, you want equal priority levels.